# Credentials couldn't be created for alchemy-api-service-free

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

I would like to create credentials for the alchemy api service.
After clicking on "Add New Credential", i get the following error:

Add New Credential
×
BXNUI0099E: The 'somename123' credential wasn't added. 
Try using a different name, or try again later. If the problem continues, click the Account and Support icon in the top menu bar, click Get help, and search for help or get support.

I did wait, used several unique credential names and i even renamed the service.
What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

Erik, please open a support ticket to get help with this issue. Follow the instructions in the error message, then click "Get in touch" and "I need help with my account or logging in". Fill out the information and Bluemix Support will respond.

For Bluemix account and "getting started" questions, open a ticket or post a question on IBM's [developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html) forum. Stack Overflow is for technical application development questions.

Comment: Hi Ralph, it wasn't an account of logging issue. 
The problem was that i didn't get credentials for the Alchemy Api service.
Next day it was generated perfectly. It only happens to be a delay issue (more than 30 minutes)

Answer (score 0):

The credentials were automatically generated later than i expected.
In my case I had to wait a day.